# Can I do anything before the user closes the application?

Tags: android

My application flies drones through missions and I want to stop the drone mission when the user closes the application, I have tried with `onDestroy()`, `onTaskRemoved()` in a service, `onBackPressed()` and with `onTerminate()` in the `Application` class, but none of this works, so I started to wonder if it is possible to do what I want to do, thanks in advance.

For example when I click the switch app button, I mean the left button on this [image](https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/gruporepublica/LKVC2DOQSND6FK65VOIO63ZSHU.jpg) and then click on close all or slide the app to close it, that way of closing the app is what I'm referring to.

Comment: mostly `onStop()` is the right place to do things before an activity is finished: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onstop

Comment: Well, `onStop()` works but I don't want to stop the drone mission every time the application is not visible, I want to stop the mission only when the application is closed.

Comment: We don't know what your definition is of "the application is closed". `ProcessLifecycleOwner` can let you know when the UI goes to the background and does not return within 700ms (to help avoid false positives from activity transitions and configuration changes).